# Auto resize icons in Ubuntu dock

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10, ubuntu-dock

I'm wondering if there is the possibility to auto resize the icons in the dock bar, e.g. if I open a lot of applications, I'd like to see all the icons in the dock bar without scrolling down with the keyboard's arrows; i.e. I'd like to see icons smaller and smaller when I gradually open new applications.

Comment: A couple of friendly pointers; please [don't add pleasantries like "thank you" to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950), we prefer focussed and to-the-point questions. Also don't add the [nautilus] tag to every question, the question has got nothing to do with Nautilus (the file manager application).

Comment: Hi @pomsky i'll follow your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Change a non exposed setting to change the behaviour from keeping the icons fixed to scaling the icons by issuing following command in the terminal or the Run dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock icon-size-fixed false
```

This will cause the icons to shrink in size so they can all fit on the screen.

Comment: Hello @vanadium, thank you for your answer. I tried it and the icon hold always the same small dimension; maybe it is needed an extension to get the desired behaviour.